# How to use mongoengine query operators when querying nested fields

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to search for text in a mongodb database using python and mongoengine. The documents in mongodb are structured as below:

```
{'title': "Food will define the future',
        'paragraphs':[
             {'text': 'Consumers in the UK are drinking less milk',
              'labels': ['market trends', 'UK']},
             {'text': 'In France, people eat a lot of cheese',
              'labels': ['market trends', 'France']}
          ]
}
```

Using mongoengine, I want to search for key words (e.g. 'milk') in the text fields of each of the documents, as follows:

```
class Article(db.Document):
    title = StringField()
    paragraphs = ListField()


selection = Article.objects(paragraphs__text__contains = 'milk')
```

It appears that the operator 'contains' is not doing anything. Only paragraphs that consist of the word 'milk' and nothing else (i.e. exact match) are being returned. What is going wrong? how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get things working. Prviously, in my models, the paragraphs were defined as a ListField(), like so:

```
class Article(db.Document):
    title = StringField()
    paragraphs = ListField()
```

Now, I've explicietly defined the paragraphs as a EmbeddedDocumentListField(), like so

```
class Paragraph(EmbeddedDocument):
    text = StringField()
    labels = ListField()

class Article(db.Document):
   title = StringField()
   paragraphs = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Paragraph)
```

After this change, the query (including the operator 'contains') behaves as expected.

I still do not really understand why the explicit definition of the embedded document was needed to get this working. So if anybody cares to explain, please...